# EXPLAIN ANALYZE in PostgreSQL : impact on the query performance?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Every time I run an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` over a query in PostgreSQL, `Execution time` decreases. Why?

I need to do some indexing on the table and this way I can't be sure if my actions which will enhance performance. What do you recommend me?

Example of the result of successive execution of the query explain (analyze, buffers) :

```
my_db=# explain (analyze, buffers)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM my_view
WHERE creation_time >= '2019-01-18 00:00:00'
  AND creation_time <= '2019-01-18 09:43:36'
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 10000;
                                                                                                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                               

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=2568854.23..2568854.23 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=24380.613..24380.614 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=14915 read=2052993, temp read=562 written=563
   ->  Sort  (cost=2568854.23..2568854.23 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=24380.611..24380.611 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (count(*)) DESC
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         Buffers: shared hit=14915 read=2052993, temp read=562 written=563
         ->  Aggregate  (cost=2568854.21..2568854.22 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=24380.599..24380.599 rows=1 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=14915 read=2052993, temp read=562 written=563
               ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=2568854.18..2568854.20 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=24339.455..24380.589 rows=40 loops=1)
                     Group Key: my_table.creation_time, my_table.some_field
                     Buffers: shared hit=14915 read=2052993, temp read=562 written=563
                     ->  Sort  (cost=2568854.18..2568854.18 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=24338.361..24357.171 rows=199309 loops=1)
                           Sort Key: my_table.creation_time, my_table.some_field
                           Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4496kB
                           Buffers: shared hit=14915 read=2052993, temp read=562 written=563
                           ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..2568854.17 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=23799.237..24142.217 rows=199309 loops=1)
                                 Workers Planned: 2
                                 Workers Launched: 2
                                 Buffers: shared hit=14915 read=2052993
                                 ->  Parallel Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..2567854.07 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=23796.695..24087.574 rows=66436 loops=3)
                                       Filter: (creation_time >= '2019-01-18 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (creation_time <= '2019-01-18 09:43:36+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 21818095
                                       Buffers: shared hit=14915 read=2052993
 Planning time: 10.982 ms
 Execution time: 24381.544 ms
(25 rows)

my_db=# explain (analyze, buffers)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM my_view
WHERE creation_time >= '2019-01-18 00:00:00'
  AND creation_time <= '2019-01-18 09:43:36'
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 10000;
                                                                                                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                               

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=2568854.23..2568854.23 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=6836.247..6836.248 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=15181 read=2052727, temp read=562 written=563
   ->  Sort  (cost=2568854.23..2568854.23 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=6836.245..6836.246 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (count(*)) DESC
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         Buffers: shared hit=15181 read=2052727, temp read=562 written=563
         ->  Aggregate  (cost=2568854.21..2568854.22 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=6836.232..6836.232 rows=1 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=15181 read=2052727, temp read=562 written=563
               ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=2568854.18..2568854.20 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=6792.036..6836.221 rows=40 loops=1)
                     Group Key: my_table.creation_time, my_table.some_field
                     Buffers: shared hit=15181 read=2052727, temp read=562 written=563
                     ->  Sort  (cost=2568854.18..2568854.18 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=6790.807..6811.469 rows=199309 loops=1)
                           Sort Key: my_table.creation_time, my_table.some_field
                           Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4496kB
                           Buffers: shared hit=15181 read=2052727, temp read=562 written=563
                           ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..2568854.17 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=6271.571..6604.946 rows=199309 loops=1)
                                 Workers Planned: 2
                                 Workers Launched: 2
                                 Buffers: shared hit=15181 read=2052727
                                 ->  Parallel Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..2567854.07 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=6268.383..6529.416 rows=66436 loops=3)
                                       Filter: (creation_time >= '2019-01-18 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (creation_time <= '2019-01-18 09:43:36+00'::timestamp with time zone)
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 21818095
                                       Buffers: shared hit=15181 read=2052727
 Planning time: 0.570 ms
 Execution time: 6837.137 ms
(25 rows)
```

Thank you.

Comment: I can speculate that maybe running `EXPLAIN` a few times gives Postgres the chance to update statistics.  Then, when you go to actually run the query, perhaps a better execution plan can be used.

Comment: Normally execution gets *slower* with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` because of the instrumentation. Can you describe in more detail what you are doing?

Comment: Probably caching of data (by Postgres or the file system). You can use `explain (analyze, buffers)` to see how much data was read from the cache

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have executed the command `explain (analyze, buffers)`and made an edit of the question. Thank you.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe My purpose is to measure the time spent by a query before adding indices and after adding them, and so to make sure that they have advantages on the read time. But if time varies a lot then I would unable to do a conclusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of PostgreSQL is this?

There are two problems:

1. A missing index:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON my_table (creation_time);
   ```
2. The value distribution statistics for `creation` time are way off, which causes PostgreSQL to underestimate the number of result rows terribly.

   This is not the immediate cause of your problem, but you should investigate what is going on there:

   - If `ANALYZE my_table` improves the estimate, see that autoanalyze runs more often for that table.
   - If `ANALYZE my_table` does not help, collect better statistics:

     ```
     ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER creation_time SET STATISTICS 1000;
     ANALYZE my_table;
     ```

The reduced execution time you observe with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` is probably due to caching effects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Did you have the conclusion of adding an index to creation_time because of the 2 filters in the SQL query or because of the numbers in the result of ANALYZE? What do you mean by *The value distribution statistics* ? I was interested only in "Execution time", but it seems that you could have more information. Thank you again.

Comment: The need for an index is obvious from the execution plan. All the time is spent in the sequential scan, and most of the rows are just discarded. Statistics is the information that PostgreSQL needs to be able to estimate result counts and cost. I cannot explain that in a SO answer, please consult the documentation on `ANALYZE`.